# Split a list into n items in a sublist with remainder being added

Tags: python, list, split, subset

I asked this last night but poorly worded it on my part.
I'm trying to take a list of:

```
['milk','eggs','beef','oranges','dog food','chips','soda','bread']
```

And split it into lists of `n` each, any remainders need to be added evenly to the lists.. so the outcome would be for `n = 3`:

```
[['milk','eggs','beef'],['oranges','dog food','chips']]
```

With a remainder of: `['soda','bread']` that would give me the final result of:

```
[['milk','eggs','beef','soda'],['oranges','dog food','chips','bread']]
```

Order doesn't matter.

Comment: What would you do if you had ten elements, and n=3? The remainder is one element long, so it can't be added evenly to all of the lists.

Comment: Then it'd be nice to add it to any list.

Comment: Matthew, your post seems to be missing a question. Do you have a specific question that we can answer for you?

Comment: What would be the best way to write a function that could take in a list like the above and return them split like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A short but efficient solution:

```
def splitList (lst, n):
    it = iter(lst)
    new = [[next(it) for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(len(lst) // n)]

    for i, x in enumerate(it):
        new[i].append(x)

    return new
```

```
>>> lst = ['milk', 'eggs', 'beef', 'oranges', 'dog food', 'chips', 'soda', 'bread']
>>> splitList(lst, 3)
[['milk', 'eggs', 'beef', 'soda'], ['oranges', 'dog food', 'chips', 'bread']]
>>> splitList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 3)
[[1, 2, 3, 10], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

This first creates a single iterator which we use for everything; so in total we only loop once over the list. The number of sublists that will be created is `len(lst) // n` (integer division rounds down), and for each sublist we take `n` values from the iterator.

After that, the remaining items will be still left in the iterator, so we can simply iterate over the rest of them and append them to the sublists directly.

Comment: This doesn't work for some splits by n. In a list of 361 items, splitting it by anything over ~50 is index out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the code below is quite simple and will serve you well. **Note that it requires the more_itertools module**

```
from more_itertools import chunked

x = ['milk','eggs','beef','oranges','dog food','chips','soda','bread']

def foo(lst,num):
    chunk = list(chunked(lst,num))

    if len(chunk[-1]) == num:
        return chunk

    for i,val in enumerate(chunk[-1]):
        chunk[i].append(val)
    del chunk[-1]

    return chunk

ans = foo(x,3)
# [['milk', 'eggs', 'beef', 'soda'], ['oranges', 'dog food', 'chips', 'bread']]
```

The code uses the chunked method from more_itertools to break your list into sub lists of size n (in your example 3), with any remainder in a final sub list. I then iterate over this final sublist and append its elements to your existing sublists. The final sublist is then deleted.

Comment: Where does `y` come from?

Comment: Sorry I changed the variable name from y to chunk and forgot that final one, edited now.

Answer (score 1):

For a list `a`, you can get the number of groups with minimum length `n` by `floor(len(a) / n)`.

```
def split(a, minSize):
    numGroups = int(len(a) / minSize)
    return [a[i::numGroups] for i in range(numGroups)]
```

Comment: @poke I thought he said "order doesn't matter"

Comment: Oh! I didn’t see that, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a stab at answering your question. I am still a little unclear on the remainder part of the list getting added, so this might require a revision at some point.
**Please let me know if the function below will serve your purpose.**

```
groceryList = ['milk', 'eggs', 'beef', 'oranges', 'dog food', 'chips', 'soda', 'bread']
outlist = []
listLength = len(groceryList)
modulus = listLength // 3
remainder = listLength % 3
print listLength, modulus, remainder
ending = 0
while modulus >= 1:
    outlist.append(groceryList[ending:ending+3])
    ending += 3
    modulus -= 1

print "value of ending", ending
outlistcounter = 0
if remainder > 0:
    while remainder != 0:
        outlist[outlistcounter].extend(groceryList[ending:ending+1])
        outlistcounter += 1
        remainder -= 1
        ending += 1
print outlist
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def split_list(lst, n):
    result = []
    # split off elements in groups of `n`
    i = 0
    while i+n <= len(lst):
        result.append([])
        for k in range(n):
            result[-1].append(lst[i+k])
        i += n
    # add the remainder to the groups
    j = 0
    while i < len(lst):
        result[j].append(lst[i])
        i += 1
        j += 1
        j %= len(result)
    return result

lst = ['milk','eggs','beef','oranges','dog food','chips','soda','bread']
for i in range(1, len(lst)):
    print(i, split_list(lst, i))
```

Result:

```
1 [['milk'], ['eggs'], ['beef'], ['oranges'], ['dog food'], ['chips'], ['soda'], ['bread']]
2 [['milk', 'eggs'], ['beef', 'oranges'], ['dog food', 'chips'], ['soda', 'bread']]
3 [['milk', 'eggs', 'beef', 'soda'], ['oranges', 'dog food', 'chips', 'bread']]
4 [['milk', 'eggs', 'beef', 'oranges'], ['dog food', 'chips', 'soda', 'bread']]
5 [['milk', 'eggs', 'beef', 'oranges', 'dog food', 'chips', 'soda', 'bread']]
6 [['milk', 'eggs', 'beef', 'oranges', 'dog food', 'chips', 'soda', 'bread']]
7 [['milk', 'eggs', 'beef', 'oranges', 'dog food', 'chips', 'soda', 'bread']]
```

This is sort of an odd thing to be doing, though, so I wonder if you might not be attacking your problem from the wrong angle.

Answer (score 0):

This works for what you seem to be asking for:

```
def f(x, n):

    if n > len(x):
        return

    y = [x[i: i + n] for i in range(0, len(x), n)]  #split the list up into lists by n

    if len(y[-1]) != n:  #if there is a remainder
        remainder = y[-1]   
        y = y[:-1]

        count = 0
        while remainder:  #while remainder is not an empty list
            for lst in y:
                lst.append(remainder.pop())  #pop the remaining items into each of the other lists 
                count += 1
    return y
```

**Example output:**

```
myList =['milk','eggs','beef','oranges','dog food','chips','soda','bread']

print f(myList, 3)

[['milk', 'eggs', 'beef', 'bread'], ['oranges', 'dog food', 'chips', 'soda']]
```

Answer (score 0):

like the above maybe a little shorter

```
def Matts_list( l, n ):
    return_list = [ l[i:i + n] for i in range( 0, len( l ), n ) ]
    # last list isn't n long
    if len( return_list[-1] ) != n :
        last = return_list.pop()
        for i in range( 0, len( last ) ):
            return_list[i % len( return_list )].append( last[i] )
    return return_list
```